# The icon on the desktop for the application of angular 2

Tags: angular

Is it possible to make an icon on the desktop for an application on Angularjs 2? Just want to make an icon by clicking which will open in the browser application url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can use [electronJs](https://electronjs.org/) to create PC application.
2. use progress web application (manifest) to to that (you can set icon to)
3. or just force user to bookmark your page

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless you're packaging your application with [electron](https://electronjs.org/), generally your application isn't intended to be ran as a desktop application.

Building an electron app with Angular isn't always the easiest way of doing it, but [here is a good guide to follow](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/desktop-apps-with-electron-and-angular/) if that is the route you want to take.